# Filtering with R and showing corresponding columns related to the selection

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to filter with R. I have the following is this correct ?

library(tidyverse)
"selction" <- Data[Data$ColumnB == "selection", ]
View("selection")

Comment: Yes, seems it will work without `tidyverse`. If you would like to use `tidyverse`, then something like `Data |> filter(ColumnB == "selection")`

Comment: To complet the answer above. You can also use the `subset()` function.   

In that case you would write `df_selected <- subset(Data, ColumnB == "selection")`